# Is there a way to define certain parts of my JSON schema as elements that must simply validate according to the core JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have some generated JSON schemas and I am trying to use JSON schema to draw up a schema for these schemas. The reason for this is that I need others to provide me with JSON schemas that match what I have generated. They can create them any way they like but I have to be able to use them in the end.

In my generated schemas I have objects where each property of the object effectively extends the core JSON schema with some small changes. Is there a way to mark an object property's schema as extending the core JSON schema? I read that there is an "extends" keyword if Draft 3 that was removed in Draft 4.

For example object properties like the one below can have entries for minItems, type, name, etc... but can also have some custom entries like readonly or target_model_type.

```
"schema": {
    "directoryDomain": {
        "target" : "device/hcmf/DirectoryDomain",
        "format" : "uri",
        "required" : true,
        "title" : "directoryDomain",
        "type" : "string",
        "name" : "directoryDomain"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also extending the core meta schema would allow for recursion in my objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly ...

One way you can extend the core schema is to use `allOf` to essentially mixin the core schema with your new fields.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#" }],
  "properties": {
    "target": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uri"
    }
  }
}
```

This schema adds an optional property `target` to the core JSON Schema definition.

The problem with this is that it is not recursive.  Only the top level of the object would understand the new field.  This is because the core JSON Schema is itself recursive.  There is no way to get the core JSON Schema to use your schema when it references itself.

The only way to extend the core JSON Schema is to make a copy of it and add your extension properties.  It smells like a DRY violation, but in practice it shouldn't be a problem because the draft-4 core JSON Schema isn't going to change.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I am little confused about how to reference that though. If I copy the core schema next to my schema, how do I reference it?

Comment: Let's say your extended JSON Schema is accessible at `/schema/extended`.  Your schemas that must validate against this should use the `$schema` keyword to point to `/schema/extended` instead of the draft-04 schema.